# Android resource files

Tags: java, android

I have a `cheerapp.mp3` in my `/res/raw` folder

so my code is

```
String filepath="/res/raw/cheerapp";   //or cheerapp.mp3
file = new File(filePath); 
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream( file );  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I got file not found. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never can you access resource files by path!**

Because they are compiled in APK file installed in Android. You can only access resource within application by access its generated resource id, from any activity (context):

```
InputStream cheerSound = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);
```

or from view:

```
InputStream cheerSound = this.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);
```

In your case, you should store sound files in external sd-card, then can access them by path. For e.g, you store your file in **`sounds`** folder on your sd-card:

```
FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/sounds/cheerapp.mp3");
```

NOTE: path starts with '/' is absolute path, because '/' represents root in Unix-like OS (Unix, Linux, Android, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Use `assets` folder and ...

```
InputStream sound = getAssets().open("filename.mp3");
```

... or `raw` folder and ...

```
InputStream sound = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```

if it doesn't help you, then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13914227/1265724)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)  to manage your resources. For example:

```
AssetManager manager = this.getContext().getAssets();
InputStream open;
try {
    open = manager.open(fileName);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```